# set time to 00:00:00 doesn't work - java

Tags: java

I want to set string that contain the new current date and the time 00:00:00.
I wrote the following code but time is set to `12:00:00`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
String today1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").
                  format(calendar.getTime())
```

I'd love to know why the code does not work or, alternatively, get another method to set time to `00:00:00`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've used [the format characters `hh`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which is the 12-hour, or am/pm, based hour scheme.

> h Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12

You've printed 12:00 am without the "am".  The time of day is set to midnight, but with your format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` the output is confusing at best.

You can do either of the following:

Switch to capital "H" characters to switch to a 24-hour clock as per your requirements:

> H Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Output:

```
2016-02-18 00:00:00
```

Or you can add the "a" format character to add the am/pm designation.

> a Am/pm marker    Text    PM

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")
```

Output:

```
2016-02-18 12:00:00 AM
```